# Selenium webdriver find_element_by_id() method in python throws error with phantomjs

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, phantomjs

web testcases on python based on selenium webdriver is having issues with using phantomjs. It is giving error on `driver.find_element_by_id("username")`.

Relevant HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" name="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
```

I heard it is time wait issue, I tried before and after the `time.sleep(10)` but still no progress:

```
time.sleep(10)
user = self.driver.find_element_by_id("username")
time.sleep(10)
```

can pleas anybody know about this like running cases with chromrdriver is working but with phantomjs it is not working even after accessing phantomjs.exe in testcases.

Comment: Relevant HTML please

Comment: <input class="form-control" name="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">    Here it is

Comment: @user3157061 : Your code looks fine to me , could you tell us what kind of exception you are getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the HTML you have provided in your comments and subsequently updated within the question, you can remove all the `time.sleep()` instances and replace them with *WebDriverWait* as follows:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  user = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control#username")))
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  user = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control' and @id='username']")))
  ```

Comment: IMO , this will not work  , though you have changed the locators and used the explicit wait, but Note that OP is  using time.sleep(10) which is worst kind of explicit wait . So we can remove the possibility  of explicit wait. Although for  giving proper answer we need to know what kind of exception he/she is getting.

Comment: I am just done with this issue; Now I am getting another one which is about the send_keys issue with using phantomjs.   I am using this code:    password = wait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='password']")))
    password.send_keys("pass1234")

Comment: @user3157061 Can you please raise a new question as per your new requirement? Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.